# how to give space in each stars in rating bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I created custom rating bar. I set default small rating bar in app. But the stars gaps are none. How to make gaps in each stars? I can give my xml file code given below:

customratingbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_normal"

        ></item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_selected"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_selected"></item>

</layer-list>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomRating" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">

        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dip</item>

    </style>
```

what mistake I make it? I don't know. How can I solve this? I beginner I don't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can contact your `UI/UX` Designer or You can re-create slice `images` using `Android Asset Studio` Tool

Upload Star `Image` at  [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_example) and set padding what you want Ex. like `8dp`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you check your image size like height and width.

Then you just add in your styles.xml --you can vary height size

```
<style name="CustomRating" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">
   <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_rating</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">40dp</item>
</style>
```

And finally you add it into your layout.

```
 <RatingBar
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:numStars="5"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  style="@style/CustomRating"
  android:id="@+id/rating_bar" />
```

Comment: i use image size 14*14 size of stars.can i reduce star image size below 14